# Chrome extension: How to remember previous previous Tab?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I made an extension that remembers the previous tab and on button click toggles between the current tab and the previous tab. Now I want to extend that to also remember the previous previous tab. This will allow to toggle between two tabs once the **current** tab is closed. However, I am struggling with the code logics. The code to toggle between current and previous tab:

```
var previousTab;
var currentTab;

// Switch tab on button click
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.update(previousTab, {selected: true});
});

// Update variables on tab change
chrome.tabs.onSelectionChanged.addListener(function(tab) {
    if (previousTab == null) {
        previousTab = tab;
    }
    if (currentTab == null) {
        currentTab = tab;
    }
    else {
        previousTab = currentTab;
        currentTab = tab;
    }
});
```

Now the code to toggle between two tabs once the current tab is closed:

```
var previousTab;
var previousPreviousTab;
var currentTab;

// Switch tab on button click
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.update(previousTab, {selected: true});
});

// Update variables on tab change
chrome.tabs.onSelectionChanged.addListener(function(tab) {
    if (previousTab == null) {
        previousTab = tab;
    }
    if (currentTab == null) {
        currentTab = tab;
    }
    if (previousPreviousTab == null) {
        previousPreviousTab = tab;
    }
    else {
        previousPreviousTab = previousTab;
        previousTab = currentTab;
        currentTab = tab;
    }
});

// Update variables on tab removal
chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(function(tab) {
    previousTab = previousPreviousTab;
});
```

Something about my logic must be wrong. When I open two new tabs and then close the most recent one, clicking on the toggle button raises the error `tabs.update: No tab with id: 698.`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea:
Create a tabs objects array (you can get all the tabs objects by calling chrome.windows.getAll(). Add a property to each tab object called "recent_use". Set it to '0' for the currently selected tab.

Anytime, a tab is selected, set its "recent_use" to 0. Add '1' to all the other tab's "recent_use". This way, over time, you will get a nice order of which tab was focused most recently.

Then depending on how many keystrokes users hits (you have to define your own key strokes here), change the tab focus to the tab that has "recent_use" equal to number of times user has hit that keystroke. This way, the solution is more generic than just previous and previousprevious tab.

(BTW, you have to also take care of modifying this tabs array anytime a new tab is created or closed. But you can easily do so by adding callbacks for those events)

In a way, this is an implementation of LFU - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_frequently_used

Comment: Thanks. Whilst this might be great in the future to switch between all tabs I only want to switch between two tabs at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Although I like Methos' generic approach I only need the ability to switch between two tabs. I finally solved it using a further boolean `wasRemoved` and a listener `onCreated`:

```
var previousPreviousTab;
var wasRemoved;
var previousTab;
var currentTab;

// Update variables on tab creation
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    previousPreviousTab = previousTab;
});

// Update variables on tab removal
chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    previousTab = previousPreviousTab;
    wasRemoved = true;
});

// Update variables on tab change
chrome.tabs.onSelectionChanged.addListener(function(tab) {
    if (previousTab == null) {
        previousTab = tab;
    }
    if (currentTab == null) {
        currentTab = tab;
    }
    else if (wasRemoved == true) {
        currentTab = tab;
        wasRemoved = false;
    }
    else {
        previousTab = currentTab;
        currentTab = tab;
    }
});
```